# How to generate unique id contains numeric value only of length 8 digits using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to generate unique id that contains numeric only using XSLT. The unique id should be of length 8 digits. I do not want to use any Java namespace to generate this unique id. I have found one solution using Java namespace that having math.random() function. but in my case Java namespace will not work because I am generating output through Saxon processor using C#.

Please provide some solution to generate unique id having lenth 8 digits only without using Java namespace in XSLT.

Comment: For which context do you need a unique id, for nodes in a single XSLT result document?

Answer (score 1):

If you accept "sequential" ids (consecutive numbers), you can use `xsl:number`.

Example script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:number level="any" count="*" format="99999999"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Details concerning `xsl:number`:

- `count="*"` causes that all elements are counted,
- `level="any"` from any nesting level,
- `format="99999999"` in the desired formatting (8 digits).

If something is still unclear, read about `xsl:number`.

Comment: Which part of your suggestion requires XSLT 2? `xsl:number` exists in XSLT 1 as well.

Comment: *Martin*, you are right. Initially I was not sure whether all used features of *xsl:number* are available in version 1.0.